# Pull images from gcr when tag name of the image is constantly changing

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, containers, jenkins-pipeline

I have made a jenkins pipeline on a kubernetes cluster.

The problem is after pipeline runs, an image is created with a new tag. And because of that i cant hardcode the tag name in the deployment yaml file.

How can i pull the image with the right tag?

Comment: Why not read the file name in pipeline and pass it to you yaml file or modify the yaml file to accept this file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon your given statement and some assumptions, You can try to re-write the Jenkins pipeline to add one more tag:latest.

```
 stage('Push image') {

    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
        app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
        app.push("latest")
    }
```

So, I think your yaml will now always pull the latest image. I hope this solves your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to work is to always push the image with a tag and in addition push one tagged latest (which will overwrite the previous latest).

This way inside your kubernetes yaml you can always pull latest.

Comment: In DaemonSets i it is little bit different. It caches and does not download the same tag image even if it has the alway pull feature. Tested on K8s 1.9.5.

Comment: You need to specifyimagePullPolicy inside the container data instead of inside the spec data